# how to select owned items or items that have been shared in access 2003

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, Items and Items_People. Each item has an id and a userid (the person who owns the item). Items_People, the table that shows who the item has been shared with, has an itemid and a userid. I want to get a list of items that the user owns or items that have been shared with that user

Here is what i have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM Items
WHERE id IN (SELECT itemid as id FROM Items_People where userid = 1)
OR userid=1
```

This does work, but I'm not sure if a nested select with WHERE IN is the fastest way of doing it. Should I be using some kind of join?

Answer (score 0):

Do some testing to see which runs faster for you.  I believe this query will work from what you stated in the question.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Items
OUTER JOIN Items_People on Items.id = Items_People.itemid AND Items_People.userid = 1
WHERE Items.userid=1
```

Obviously, run this query first to make sure it gives you the same results. Then test each query to see if you notice any difference in speed.